# Adding sensitive ENV variables to a custom vscode extension?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-devops, yaml, vscode-extensions

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can add a secret api key to my vscode extension to allow it to make authorised requests to an external api?

When running locally, I have managed with a .env file and a launch.json config, but once it is published I do not know where to actually store the variable so that it is:

1. Accessible by the published extension/app
2. Safely stored

Any help appreciated, thanks

I haven't found any docs for this, but if anyone knows of a guide to add the env var to azure, that would be great.

Comment: To me this sounds impossible. I could be wrong. But your extension will run on either a Microsoft hosted agent or the customer's own machine. In the own machine scenario they could take your key from memory regardless how you acquire it. Most extensions that require calling a secured API require the customer to enter their own key.

Comment: Thanks @juunas. That seems sensible. I was hoping to prototype something with some friends with little friction involved, but I'll add an input field on activation

Comment: Curious if anyone has any suggestions on the best way to store a users api key on their local machine? What directory should I use and is this done in a standard way? It would look somthing like:

step 1: activate extension
step 2: input apikey
step 3: save api key to file in directory

Comment: I opened another thread for an updated question specifically directed at safely storing an API key locally:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75426829/safely-storing-a-users-api-key-locally-to-be-used-in-vscode-extension