# Safely storing a users API key locally to be used in vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, local-storage, vscode-extensions, api-key, secret-key

I have developed a vscode extension that allows a user to retrieve information from an api. The api requires a secret api key. I do not want to use a single API key for all users but rather allow them to provide their own API key. The steps in my vscode extension would look something like:

1. Activate extension
2. Add API key through prompted input
3. Store a users API key somehwere on their local machine.

My question is about the best practices for storing an API key on their machine. Where is the best place to store it? WOuld it be different for Windows and Mac? Is it safe to store this file locally? Should I auto-delete the API key if the extension is disabled? I am looking for insight on how best to do this, and appreciate any responses.

Comment: You might get some idea from GitHub's extension for VS Code, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-pull-request-github/blob/611d819b535b98c0066d0ef7e42e32bcb2a2b24d/src/github/credentials.ts#L40